# Object expected Hash found, Ruby on Rails, Rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

I have written up a Rest api for my website. Currently I have it so that a user has many computers that they can own. I am trying to send a json payload that updates the user account with a computer. For testing this is what I send:

```
 {"auth_token"=>"AiprpscAqN6hnvNDHSwh",
 "user"=>"{"id":1,
 "username":"Rizowski",
 "email":"test@gmail.com",
 "computer":[{"id":0,
    "user_id":1,
    "name":"Desktop",
    "enviroment":"Windows 8",
    "ip_address":"192.168.1.10",
    "account":[]}]}",
 "format"=>"json",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Once I send it, the Rails controller receives it and parses the request into a hash using the JSON.parse method. Once I try to save the user object it says this:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Api::V1::UsersController#update 
Computer(#51701664) expected, got Hash(#17322756)
```

Side question: I am still trying to completely understand rails and rest, but is it a good practice to send a computer object as I am? OR should I be sending the computer data through my computer api controller?

Comment: You don't want to save a hash, you need to create an object from it. The last question is a bit non-sensical; you're calling a REST API, you can only send data the endpoint understands (e.g., JSON, XML, form data, etc.) You *are* sending through the API controller.

Comment: By the way, the data you have shown here is invalid, the double quotes around the user would make it an invalid hash. Are you stitching multiple things together here?

Comment: @DanielEvans Yeah I am trying to send 1 object(user) with a list of computers that are associated with that user.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry about that, I was meaning sending the JSON the way I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your error is to use the key `computer_attributes` instead of `computer`.

This is a normal practice for strongly associated and hierarchical data. If `computers` are going to be updated independently of user, you should certainly use its own controller.

Comment: Ah, Ok I kept reading about that attribute and I wasn't sure where I was supposed to put it. I kept thinking that I was supposed to put it in my user model class. But that cleared it up for me. Thank you.